# Creating an IoT Application in Bluemix results with error BXNUI0005E

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

While creating an Application in Bluemix trial account, I encountered an error BXNUI0005E: The "" application could not be added.

I tried creating the application using the Boiler plate "IoT For Electronics Starter" and it continuously failed with the above message.

Even tried from a different environment with a different App name, the results remained same.

Answer (score 1):

After checking ahead found that trial accounts in Bluemix can only create 4 services. 
The IoT for Electronics starter creates the below three different services

- Internet of Things platform
- IoT for electronics
- Mobile Access client

I already had a simple node.js app associated to two different services.
As the boiler plate was unable to create these new services, the new application failed with error BXNUI0005E.

Once the other services were removed, the application created fine.